# Android mail search using Exchange Activesync

Tags: android, email, exchange-server, activesync

Is there is way to search mail in Exchange server using active sync protocol in android, i tried in many ways but it works for Global adress lookup but not for mails. can anybody please give the solution it realy helps me. please suggest the any link for clease understanding of Exchange mailbox store.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219024(v=EXCHG.80).aspx) is an example from the ActiveSync Protocol specification. You will first need to get the list of folders using the FolderSync command, and then use the ServerId returned to search the folders. 
More information in my comment [here](http://vivekiyer.net/corporate-addressbook/comment-page-1/#comment-527).

P.S. Might be useful to add an activesync tag to this question.