# Exchange server search from android email

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, activesync

I am trying to search exchange server mailbox by the following command from a android  client.

```
<Search>  
    <Store>
        <Name>Mailbox</Name>
        <Query> 
            <And>
            <Class>Email</Class>  
            <CollectionId>5</CollectionId>
            <FreeText>a</FreeText>
           </And>
        </Query>
    <Options>
        <Range>0-4</Range>
    </Options>
 </Store>
```

But the response is a status error...

```
<Search>
<Status>1</Status>
<Response>
    <Store>
    <Status>2</Status>
    .............
```

Any pointers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you finally solve it?

Answer (score 0):

How  did get CollectionId ? You should use `cmd = FolderSync` to get server id.

let collectionId = server id

you could see this

[Android mail search using Exchange Activesync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178553/android-mail-search-using-exchange-activesync)